# NameError: name 'secret_dec' is not defined

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Пытаюсь вывести результат работы функции в `label` через переменную

```
   def defbuttonencrypt(self):
        self.sec = secret_dec
        if self.res:
            decode_string(video=self.res)
            self.label.setText(self.sec)
```

я переменной `self.sec` присвоил значение 
глобальной переменной `global secret_dec`, но почему то получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mazafaker/python/SUPER PROJECT v228/project stegano/main.py", line 194, in defbuttonencrypt
    self.sec = secret_dec
NameError: name 'secret_dec' is not defined
```

полный код:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# импортируемые модули для проекта
import os,sys
import pathlib
import wave
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import shutil
from math import ceil
from subprocess import call,STDOUT
from tqdm import tqdm
from stegano import lsb
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel,QProgressBar

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(430, 538)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 241, 17))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.browse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 190, 89, 25))
        self.browse.setObjectName("browse")
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, -10, 251, 81))
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./logo.png"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
        self.filename = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.filename.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 221, 25))
        self.filename.setObjectName("filename")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 220, 441, 31))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.btncryptmsg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btncryptmsg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 110, 171, 21))
        self.btncryptmsg.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.btncryptmsg.setObjectName("btncryptmsg")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 60, 471, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 161, 17))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 221, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.btnencryptmsg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnencryptmsg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 140, 171, 21))
        self.btnencryptmsg.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.btnencryptmsg.setObjectName("btnencryptmsg")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 411, 111))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 430, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Укажите путь к видео  файлу:"))
        self.browse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор..."))
        self.btncryptmsg.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "зашифровать текст "))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сообщение:"))
        self.btnencryptmsg.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расшифровать текст"))

# Function to split the message.
def split_string(split_str,count=10):
    per_c=math.ceil(len(split_str)/count)
    c_cout=0
    out_str=''
    split_list=[]
    for s in split_str:
        out_str+=s
        c_cout+=1
        if c_cout == per_c:
            split_list.append(out_str) # The message is divided into substrings
            out_str=''
            c_cout=0
    if c_cout!=0:
        split_list.append(out_str)
    return split_list


# As we know video is a collection of frames, where each frame is a picture.
# This function will extract each frame along with audio from the video.
def frame_extraction(video):
    if not os.path.exists("./temp"):
        os.makedirs("temp")
    temp_folder="./temp" # Temporary folder created to store the frames and audio from the video.
    print("[INFO] temp directory is created")
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    count = 0
    while True:
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(temp_folder, "{:d}.png".format(count)), image)
        count += 1


# This function would embed the splitted string into the frames extracted from the video.
def encode_string(input_string,root="./temp/"):
    split_string_list=split_string(input_string)   # Acquire the splitted string from the message.
    for i in range(0,len(split_string_list)):
        f_name="{}{}.png".format(root,i)
        secret_enc=lsb.hide(f_name,split_string_list[i])   # Вставка разделенной строки в каждый кадр.
        secret_enc.save(f_name)                            # Сохранил кадры после сокрытия строк.
        print("[INFO] frame {} holds {}".format(f_name,lsb.reveal(f_name)))
    print("Сообщение хранится в файле  Embedded_Video.mp4 ")


# This function would decode the hidden message by extracting frames from the video
def decode_string(video):
    frame_extraction(video)        # Extracting each frame from the video
    secret=[]
    root="./temp/"
    for i in range(len(os.listdir(root))):
        f_name="{}{}.png".format(root,i)
        global secret_dec
        secret_dec=lsb.reveal(f_name)         # Выявление сообщения внутри каждой строки
        if secret_dec == None:
            break
        secret.append(secret_dec)
    print(''.join([i for i in secret]))
    clean_temp()

# This function would delete the temp directory
def clean_temp(path="./temp"):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)
        print("[INFO] temp files are cleaned up")


# This function would extraxt audio from the video so as to stitch them back later.
def input_main(f_name):
    input_string = w.i
    frame_extraction(f_name)
    # The call function would be used to extract the audio and then stitch it again properly with the frames extracted.
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i",f_name, "-q:a", "0", "-map", "a", "temp/audio.mp3", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    encode_string(input_string)
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "temp/%d.png" , "-vcodec", "png", "temp/Embedded_Video.mp4", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "temp/Embedded_Video.mp4", "-i", "temp/audio.mp3", "-codec", "copy", "Embedded_Video.mp4", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    clean_temp()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.res = None  # !!!

        # !!! тут логика
        self.btncryptmsg.clicked.connect(self.defbuttncrypt)
        self.btnencryptmsg.clicked.connect(self.defbuttonencrypt)
        self.browse.clicked.connect(self.clicker)

    def clicker(self):
        self.res, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './')
        if self.res:  # +++
            self.filename.setText(self.res)  # !!!  - [0]

    def defbuttncrypt(self):
        self.i = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        #input_main(f_name=w.res)
        if self.res:  # +++
            input_main(f_name=self.res)  # +++

    def defbuttonencrypt(self):
        self.sec = secret_dec
        if self.res:
            decode_string(video=self.res)
            self.label.setText(slef.sec)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    #    uw = Ui_MainWindow()                                      # ---                           # +++
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Чтобы переменная стала глобальной ее нужно создать на уровне модуля, а у вас она где-то в функциях создается и используется. Глобальные переменные лучше не использовать, лучше явно передавать/возвращать из функций переменные

Comment: как мне тогда получить и зтой  переменной в функции значения в другую функцию?

Comment: `нужно создать на уровне модуля`, там же где, у вас находятся функции, типа `split_string`

Comment: не помогает    spilit_string = secret_dec
NameError: name 'secret_dec' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу проверить ваш пример, но предложу попробовать то, как я это понимаю.
Я оставил некоторые комментарии в тексте приложения, прочтите из и пробуйте запустить.

```
import sys
import os
import pathlib
import wave
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import shutil
from math import ceil
from subprocess import call,STDOUT
from tqdm import tqdm
from stegano import lsb
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel,QProgressBar


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(430, 538)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 241, 17))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.browse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 190, 89, 25))
        self.browse.setObjectName("browse")
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, -10, 251, 81))
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./logo.png"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
        self.filename = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.filename.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 221, 25))
        self.filename.setObjectName("filename")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 220, 441, 31))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.btncryptmsg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btncryptmsg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 110, 171, 21))
        self.btncryptmsg.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.btncryptmsg.setObjectName("btncryptmsg")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 60, 471, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 161, 17))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 221, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.btnencryptmsg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnencryptmsg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 140, 171, 21))
        self.btnencryptmsg.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.btnencryptmsg.setObjectName("btnencryptmsg")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 411, 111))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 430, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Укажите путь к видео  файлу:"))
        self.browse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор..."))
        self.btncryptmsg.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "зашифровать текст "))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сообщение:"))
        self.btnencryptmsg.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расшифровать текст"))

# Function to split the message.
def split_string(split_str,count=10):
    per_c=math.ceil(len(split_str)/count)
    c_cout=0
    out_str=''
    split_list=[]
    for s in split_str:
        out_str+=s
        c_cout+=1
        if c_cout == per_c:
            split_list.append(out_str) # The message is divided into substrings
            out_str=''
            c_cout=0
    if c_cout!=0:
        split_list.append(out_str)
    return split_list


# As we know video is a collection of frames, where each frame is a picture.
# This function will extract each frame along with audio from the video.
def frame_extraction(video):
    if not os.path.exists("./temp"):
        os.makedirs("temp")
    temp_folder="./temp" # Temporary folder created to store the frames and audio from the video.
    print("[INFO] temp directory is created")
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    count = 0
    while True:
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(temp_folder, "{:d}.png".format(count)), image)
        count += 1


# This function would embed the splitted string into the frames extracted from the video.
def encode_string(input_string,root="./temp/"):
    split_string_list=split_string(input_string)   # Acquire the splitted string from the message.
    for i in range(0,len(split_string_list)):
        f_name="{}{}.png".format(root,i)
        secret_enc=lsb.hide(f_name,split_string_list[i])   # Вставка разделенной строки в каждый кадр.
        secret_enc.save(f_name)                            # Сохранил кадры после сокрытия строк.
        print("[INFO] frame {} holds {}".format(f_name,lsb.reveal(f_name)))
    print("Сообщение хранится в файле  Embedded_Video.mp4 ")


# Эта функция будет декодировать скрытое сообщение, извлекая кадры из видео.
def decode_string(video):
    frame_extraction(video)        # Extracting each frame from the video
    secret = []
    root="./temp/"
    for i in range(len(os.listdir(root))):
        f_name="{}{}.png".format(root, i)

# !!!        
#        global secret_dec
        secret_dec = lsb.reveal(f_name)    # Выявление сообщения внутри каждой строки
        if secret_dec == None:
            break
        secret.append(secret_dec)
    print(''.join([i for i in secret]))
    clean_temp()

# !!!    
    return secret                         # secret - это список     # +++  !!!


# This function would delete the temp directory
def clean_temp(path="./temp"):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)
        print("[INFO] temp files are cleaned up")


# This function would extraxt audio from the video so as to stitch them back later.
def input_main(f_name):
    input_string = w.i
    frame_extraction(f_name)
    # The call function would be used to extract the audio and then stitch it again properly with the frames extracted.
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i",f_name, "-q:a", "0", "-map", "a", "temp/audio.mp3", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    encode_string(input_string)
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "temp/%d.png" , "-vcodec", "png", "temp/Embedded_Video.mp4", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "temp/Embedded_Video.mp4", "-i", "temp/audio.mp3", "-codec", "copy", "Embedded_Video.mp4", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
    clean_temp()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.res = None  # !!!

        # !!! тут логика
        self.btncryptmsg.clicked.connect(self.defbuttncrypt)
        
        # расшифровать текст
        self.btnencryptmsg.clicked.connect(self.defbuttonencrypt)
        self.browse.clicked.connect(self.clicker)

    def clicker(self):
        self.res, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './')
        if self.res:  # +++
            self.filename.setText(self.res)  # !!!  - [0]

    def defbuttncrypt(self):
        self.i = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        #input_main(f_name=w.res)
        if self.res:  # +++
            input_main(f_name=self.res)  # +++

# !!!
    def defbuttonencrypt(self):
    
#        self.sec = secret_dec
        
        if self.res:
#            decode_string(video=self.res)
            sec = decode_string(video=self.res)     # <--- в sec возвращаем результат
                                                    # работы функции decode_string().
            print(* sec, sep='\n')                  # Посмотрите что там и определитесь
                                                    # что вы хотите видеть в self.label
#            self.label.setText(slef.sec)           #                        vvvvvvvvvv
            self.label.setText(str(sec))            # <---------------------< vvvvvvvv    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    #    uw = Ui_MainWindow()                                      # ---                           # +++
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Я почти был у цели, спасибо еще раз за помощь! ты гений!)  у меня все плохо с знаниями, но я исправлюсь)

Comment: @joparez228 пожалуйста.